# How to use SetWindowPtrLong to set a custom window procedure to a child control?

Tags: c++, winapi

Now I have a button control to which I want to assign a custom window procedure,

```
HWND buttonControl = CreateWindow(
    L"BUTTON", 
    L"Click Me!", 
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
    100, 100, 200, 50,
    hWnd, //Parent Window,
    0,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
```

The Window Procedure :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK customWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    
    ...
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

---

I have found some answers that **almost* answers my question, such as:

- [How to change a window procedure at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648180/c-changing-hwnd-window-procedure-in-runtime)
- [Why you have to save the *original window procedure* of the window.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=18333)

---

My question is :

after *registering* a class like,

```
WNDCLASS button_wc = { 0 };
button_wc.lpszClassName = L"BUTTON";
button_wc.lpfnWndProc = customWndProc; // Custom window procedure from above.

RegisterClass(&button_wc);
```

How am I supposed to assign it to the button control?
I know that I have to use `SetWindowPtrLong` to assign it to the button control, but I don't understand how to do it. In the above [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=18333) it is also said that I have to save the old window procedure?!

So am I supposed to call `SetWindowPtrLong` and assign the value when I am creating the `WNDCLASS` to `WNDCLASS::lpfnWndProc` like:

```
button_wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowPtrLong(buttonControl, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&customWndProc);
```

or am I supposed to assign it somewhere else?

---

**EDIT:**
This is how I am assigning the custom *window procedure*:

```cpp
LRESULT customWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {
    switch(message) {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            std::cout << "CREATE" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: {
            std::cout << "LBUTTONDOWN" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
                        
            HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(20, 140, 240));
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, brush);

            DeleteObject(brush);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
        }
   }

   return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

SetWindowSubclass(buttonControl, customWndProc, 17, 0); //Setting the subclass
```

But the *window procedure* is not catching the `WM_CREATE` and `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` messages but it is catching `WM_PAINT` messages?! Am I doing something wrong?

---

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: The "BUTTON" window class already exists, so do not create it.

Comment: No, I want custom features on the *button* that's why I am assigning a custom *window procedure* to it.

Comment: The simple answer is: You don't. See [Subclassing Controls Using ComCtl32.dll version 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview#subclassing-controls-using-comctl32dll-version-6) for instructions on how to properly subclass controls.

Comment: `SetWindowSubclass(/*button control*/, /*Instead of a WNDPROC a SUBWNDPROC*/, /*Any arbitrary number*/, /*But what to put here?*/)`

Comment: Anything your application needs. If you don't need to access any data from within your subclass procedure, then pass a `nullptr`.

Comment: @IInspectable OK, but I'm still not receiving `WM_CREATE` messages

Comment: Right. The value you specify there is passed on to your subclass procedure. You could allocate a structure on the heap that stores state information, for example, and pass a pointer to it as the `dwRefData`. That's just a common pattern in the Win32 API. It serves a similar purpose as the `lpParam` in the `CreateWindow` call.

Comment: @IInspectable Oh ok

Comment: @IInspectable Ok, I'm dumb I am assigning the *custom window procedure* after the window is created, ***Obviously*** I'm not going to receive any `WM_CREATE` messages.

Comment: @IInspectable Anyway, thank very much for suggesting `SetWindowSubclass`. It was way easier than whatever I was trying to do. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you need your window subclass procedure to be installed prior to receiving `WM_CREATE`/`WM_NCCREATE` messages you would have to register a (local) [CBT hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977(v=vs.85)) (I *think* you can subclass a window from a `HCBT_CREATEWND` handler, though I never actually tried).

Comment: @IInspectable I don't think I would ever need it to be installed prior to receiving `WM_CREATE`. But it is still good to know.

Comment: There's also a technique known as "super-classing", where you register a custom class (with its own class name) and then instead of calling `DefWindowProc` (or `DefSubclassProc` as you've done in your example below) you use `CallWindowProc` to call the original window procedure of the class you're augmenting.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm creating a *custom window procedure* for a child control,

```cpp
HWND buttonControl = CreateWindow(
   L"BUTTON",
   L"Click me!",
   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
   100, 100, 200, 50,
   hWnd, // Parent Window
   0, 
   NULL,
   NULL
);
```

---

The *custom window procedure* :

```cpp
LRESULT customWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) 
{
   switch(message) {
       case WM_LBUTTONDOWN : {
           std::cout << "Clicked" << std::endl;
           break;
       }
       case WM_LBUTTONUP : {
           std::cout << "Un-Clicked" << std::endl;
           break;
       }
   }

   return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); // A "DefWindowPrc" but for subclasses
}
```

---

Now I am assigning the *custom window procedure* to my control using [`SetWindowSubclass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass) like:

```cpp
SetWindowSubclass(
    buttonControl, // The window we want the subclass to be assigned to
    customWndProc, // The custom window procedure we defined above.
    17, // Any unique number to identify this subclass with
    (DWORD_PTR)nullptr // As we don't want to access data from our subclass we pass a nullptr.
)
```

---

This is all defined in [commctrl.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/).

And that's all I had to do to assign a *custom window procedure* to a child control.

Thanks to @IInspectable for the answer.